# Error Loading Zend Gdata framework into Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, frameworks, gdata, zend-loader

I am trying to use the Zend Gdata framework with wordpress but I am having some issues.
Now everything works perfectly fine when I test on localhost with XAMPP. However on my web server my code breaks down.

Here is my code to include the framework.

```
`set_include_path(TEMPLATEPATH . '/includes/');
require_once ('Zend/Loader.php'); 
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_Youtube');`
```

That code produces the following error.

Warning: Zend_Loader::include_once(Zend/Gdata/Youtube.php) [zend-loader.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/damain/public_html/mysite.com/wp-content/themes/mysite/includes/Zend/Loader.php on line 146

Warning: Zend_Loader::include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening 'Zend/Gdata/Youtube.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/damain/public_html/mysite.com/wp-content/themes/mysite/includes/') in /home/damain/public_html/mysite.com/wp-content/themes/mysite/includes/Zend/Loader.php on line 146

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Exception' with message 'File "Zend/Gdata/Youtube.php" does not exist or class "Zend_Gdata_Youtube" was not found in the file' in /home/damain/public_html/mysite.com/wp-content/themes/mysite/includes/Zend/Loader.php:99 Stack trace: #0 /home/damain/public_html/mysite.com/wp-content/themes/mysite/includes/modules/yt_link_checker.php(19): Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_Yout...') #1 /home/damain/public_html/mysite.com/wp-includes/plugin.php(405): load_zend_gdata('') #2 /home/damain/public_html/mysite.com/wp-admin/admin.php(111): do_action('load_zend_gdata', Array) #3 /home/damain/public_html/mysite.com/wp-admin/index.php(10): require_once('/home/damain/...') #4 {main} thrown in /home/damain/public_html/mysite.com/wp-content/themes/mysite/includes/Zend/Loader.php on line 99

I cannot seem to figure this issue out. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

The best solution in this case is to run the script requiring the Zend Loader and use `var_dump(get_include_path())` to see what the server says the path is. Then keep modifying the php.ini include_path until the script finds it.

In your case, I'm not sure if 'damain' is supposed to be 'domain'. My include path which finally worked was:

/home2/thelove6/public_html/zf/ZendGdata/library" `thelove6` being the username.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look to see if those files exist in those directories? (/mysite/includes/Zend/Loader.php) and they have the correct permissions? It sounds like that could very well be the issue.  The other thing to check with a simple `phpinfo()` would be that you have all of the libraries install on the live server.

Comment: Yes I did the directories and files are there. However I never did anything with permissions. What permissions are those files supposed to have?

Comment: I am not exactly sure but they should be executable by the system.  I would try 777 to see if that is the issue, if not go back the the perms it was originally set at.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the possible reason is: You're not using the proper case for the classname. For the version 1.11.11, it will be `Zend_Gdata_YouTube` rather than Zend_Gdata_Youtube.

Windows OS is ignoring the case, whereas the Linux server does not. Hope this will solve your problem, just look at the proper case of the Class or filenames.